# How to return a QColor as the QBackgroundRole in QTableView which has preset stylesheet in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtableview, qtstylesheets

I encountered a strange problem as stated in the title.

I have a QTableView.

```
self.table = QTableView()
```

Then set some QSS to it.

```
self.table.setStyleSheet('''
QTableView {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    gridline-color: red;
    color: red;
}
QTableView::item{
    border-color: none;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    gridline-color: rgb(44, 49, 60);
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
QTableView::item:selected{
    background-color: blue;
}
''')
```

Then I try to return a QColor inside the model (QAbstractTableModel), It just won't work. If I removed the style sheet, then it worked. Does anyone which line of my QSS created the problem?

```
if role == Qt.BackgroundRole and index.row() == self.headStart:
            # Set header start color
            return QColor(208, 74, 2)
```

I need the stylesheet, at the same time I also need Qt.BackgroundRole to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a [partially known](https://forum.qt.io/topic/95940/model-backgroundrole-overridden-by-style-sheet/7) and [unresolved bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70100), for which when background colors or borders are specified for the `::item` selector, the color role is ignored (since it's overridden by the stylesheet).

A possible solution is to set an item delegate and fill the underlying rectangle *before* calling the default implementation.

```py
class BackgroundDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        if index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole):
            qp.fillRect(opt.rect, index.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole))
        super().paint(qp, opt, index)

class SomeClass(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.delegate = BackgroundDelegate(self.table)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
```

In case this doesn't properly work due to some OS style issues, try setting `background: transparent` for the base item selector too.