# PyQt5 : Change font color in one cell if row is selected (QAbstractTableModel)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` with model and want to change the foreground color in a specific column if i select a row.
I tried something out with a `QStyledItemDelegate` but nothing works.
could anybody help me?

The `SelectionBehavior` of the `tableView` is `SelectRows`.

With StyleSheets on the Tableview i set the color to `'color:rgb(255,255,255)'` and the selection-color to  `'color:rgb(255, 181, 62)'`.
But if i select a row, the color of column 8 should be stay `'color:rgb(255,255,255)'`

thank you very much

**edit:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class reportDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(reportDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)

        color = QtGui.QColor(255,255,255)

        if index.column() == 8:
            color = QtGui.QColor(255,255,255)
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
                option.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QtGui.QColor(255,255,255))
        else:
            if option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
                option.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Normal, QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText, QtGui.QColor(255, 181, 62))
        option.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Text, color)
```

Now i got it.
It works. But i have another problem.
When i doubleclick on a row, a QDialog opens.
If the QDialog is open, the color of the selected row switched to black, but it should stay white.
I dont know the state of the selected, but inactive or whatelse row, so i dont know how the make the row white in this state.

**edit:**
Now it works fine.
I deactivated the color in the meantime when I tried something. Now i activated it again and the row stays white.

If someone has a better solution for all the things above, I would be very grateful.

Comment: "I tried something out with a QStyledItemDelegate but nothing works". Would you care to [edit] your post and show us your attempts, so that we can understand what was possibly wrong with it and eventually tell you how to fix it?

Comment: sorry, i cant. I deleted all what i tried.

Comment: Then try again and then provide a [mre].

Comment: Please notify us whenever you edit a post after a request, we cannot follow *any* post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreground ("text") color used for *selected* items is set using the `HighlightedText` [`ColorRole`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorRole-enum).

When you also specify the [`ColorGroup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#ColorGroup-enum), the color set will only be valid for that selected group, while reverting to the parent (or system) palette if the inherited role isn't set.

If the view becomes *inactive* (aka: unfocused), and you explicitly set the color for another color group (`Normal`, in your case), Qt will use the default color for any other role *and/or* group.

You need to set the palette color for the role and *all* color groups, so just *omit* the color group at all:

```py
class reportDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)

        if index.column() == 8:
            highlightColor = QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255)
        else:
            highlightColor = QtGui.QColor(255, 181, 62)

        option.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.HighlightedText,
            highlightColor)
```

Notes:

- QPalette always stores colors as *QBrush* objects, even when using `QColor` or `Qt.GlobalColor` arguments (it internally creates QBrush objects anyway);
- using `setStyleSheet()` with the `::item` selector and the `background` property will **always** override the background, no matter if the `Qt.BackgroundRole` is set (see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166527);
- the `QStyle.State_Selected` is usually irrelevant with this kind of checking, as the style will always verify the state anyway; just ignore the state, set the palette color no matter what, and let the default implementation do the rest; this is important as it's the `paint()` responsibility to *finally* choose the actual color to use;