# How to style QListView items according to underlying object property while applying styles from a stylesheet

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, pyside2, qtstylesheets, qlistview

I have a `QListView` which uses a model to display custom `Alarm` objects as text applying different colors based on the `Alarm.level` attribute of each object.

```py
@dataclass
class Alarm:
  name: str
  level: int
  started_at: datetime


class Alarm_Viewer_Model(QAbstractListModel):

    def __init__(
            self,
            alarms: List[Alarm] = None,
            alarm_colors: Dict[int, QColor] = None,
            *args,
            **kwargs
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._alarms = alarms or []
        self._alarm_colors = alarm_colors or {}

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        alarm = self._alarms[index.row()]
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            dt = alarm.started_at.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
            return f"{dt} - {alarm.level.name} - {alarm.name}"
        elif role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            alarm_color = self._alarm_colors.get(alarm.level, Qt.black)
            return QBrush(alarm_color)
```

This works fine until I try load a stylesheet which applies a default text color to all widgets. In this case the stylesheet color overrides whatever color is set by the model (other questions, like [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/95940/model-backgroundrole-overridden-by-style-sheet/10) or [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/140101/palette-overriding-style-sheet/6), confirm that this is normal Qt behaviour).

My question is: how can I still have control over the style of each list item while a generic style is applied via the stylesheet?

- One way I tried to do this (which is also suggested in one of the links) is to have the model set a custom property on the item which could be accessed by the stylesheet with an appropriate selector (e.g. `QListView::item[level=1] { color: red; }`). However, I could not find any way to set the property in the list view item: is it even possibile?
- Another way that was suggested (but have not yet tried) is via QStyledItemDelegate. However from what I have seen, even if it works, it looks way overkill: is it the only way to solve this?

PS: I tagged this with PySide2 as I am using it, but am more interested in the general Qt behaviour: finding a way to implement it in PySide2 specifically is a secondary problem for now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a QColor as the QBackgroundRole in QTableView which has preset stylesheet in PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68162885/how-to-return-a-qcolor-as-the-qbackgroundrole-in-qtableview-which-has-preset-sty)

Comment: When a view has a QSS that define item colors, it completely ignores the background/foreground roles of the model. It may seem counter intuitive, but that's how QSS work: they *override* the painting based on their rules, and as long as one property is set, all properties for the same context must be set, otherwise the default is always used, meaning that any *styled* painting reverts to the default, which is no background painting for items. The only way to work around this is by overriding the `paint` function of the delegate, draw the background, and then call the default implementation.

Comment: Note that you can't use property selectors for QSS in this case, because they use Qt properties, which are only available for QObject (items/indexes are not QObjects). Properties are evaluated from the target widget, meaning that your attempt above will make all QListView instances, having a `level` property set to 1, display all their items in red.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante: so it looks like QStyledItemDelegate is the way to go after all. How would I use the paint() method to simply change the foreground/text color, while keeping all other style rules?

Comment: Well, changing the foreground is a bit more delicate: the QStyleSheetStyle internally alters the QStyleOptionViewItem palette based on the QSS that is finally applied to the view, and right before calling `drawControl()`. A possible alternative (as long you don't set drawing rules for items, like borders) would be to use a QProxyStyle and change the palette based on the foreground role of the index (if it's set).

Answer (score 1):

Qt Style Sheets are fun and useful, but they also are double-edged swords.

An important thing to always be aware of is that they mostly respect the concept behind CSS, from which they originate.

When a QSS is set, it can possibly, if not *completely* override the default behavior, similarly to what happens in web browsers.

In the Qt world, this works with a fundamental hierarchy:

- a basic, primitive style (QCommonStyle) that provides access to elementary functions that are common to all systems;

  - a built-in style (QWindowsStyle) that has default fallbacks for the above functions;

    - a OS/system/user style set that eventually calls back the default implementations;

      - a QStyleSheetStyle that is privately set for any widget that may be affected by a QSS, possibly overriding the underlying style of the widget;

Remember that a style will always have the final word on how any aspect of the widget is eventually drawn, as long as you call its functions. That's also why it is wrong to set generic properties on parent/container widgets.

Whenever a QSS affects a widget in some way, it accesses its render rules and eventually reverts back to the upper level of the style hierarchy, but it will **always** override

If a `QAbstractItemDelegate::item` rule is set, this means that it will completely override any underlying QStyle function.

When the `paint()` function of QStyledItemDelegate is called, it will just call `initStyleOption()` with the given option and index, and then *asks* the style to paint it. How the item is finally drawn is completely up to the style. Normally, styles follow the `Qt.BackgroundRole` (and/or the give `option.backgroundBrush`) and `Qt.ForegroundRole`, but that's just an assumption: a style may decide to use its own colors and completely ignore the model.

This brings us back to the point: as said above, a QStyleSheetStyle always overrides the underlying QStyle as soon as some of its properties are set.

Setting the `color` or `background[-color]` properties in a QSS means that those rules are built *upon* the default styling, which is also valid for subcontrols like `::item`.

Now, for generic widget properties, it's quite easy to access the palette that the QStyleSheetStyle updates, but, unfortunately, there's no direct access to subcontrols rules.

As explained in a comment to the related [QTBUG-75191](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75191), they don't plan to change the current behavior. That may be annoying, but I completely understand it.

So, how can we work around this?

Well, it depends. As the comment above says:

- For full control over rendering of items you can implement a custom delegate.

I explained it in the beginning: QSS can be double-edged swords. If you want to use them, you have to accepts their shortcomings.

As long as you have complete and absolute control over the views, their models and the stylesheet syntax, you can go along with a solution similar to [the one you already got](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77459596/2001654) (but you should probably get the `textRect` from the style `subElementRect()`, using `SE_ItemViewItemText`, and finally paint with `drawItemText`).

Unfortunately, this won't solve all problems.
For example, while the [answer linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166527) may provide a possible solution, it won't work well for a QSS that also sets borders, margins and paddings.

A possible (but *bad*) work around can be to use a fake view that is used as style target, eventually altering its stylesheet for each item. That's not good, it obviously is a terrible choice if you have *lots* of items, but it may still be an alternative:

```py
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent: QAbstractItemView):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._fakeView = parent.__class__(parent)
        self._fakeView.setObjectName('_fakeCopy')
        self._fakeView.hide()

    def _makeQssColor(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, QColor):
            return 'rgba({},{},{},{})'.format(*data.getRgb())
        elif isinstance(data, (int, Qt.GlobalColor)):
            return 'rgba({},{},{},{})'.format(*QColor(data).getRgb())
        elif isinstance(data, QBrush) and data.style():
            if data.color().isValid():
                return 'rgba({},{},{},{})'.format(*data.color().getRgb())
            # TODO: build from data.gradient() if it's not None
            # TODO: if not data.texture().isNull(), but probably impossible

    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        qss = []
        if index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole):
            parsed = self._makeQssColor(index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole))
            if parsed:
                qss.append('background: {};'.format(parsed))
        if index.data(Qt.ForegroundRole):
            parsed = self._makeQssColor(index.data(Qt.ForegroundRole))
            if parsed:
                qss.append(
                    'color: {0};\n\tselection-color: {0};'.format(parsed))
        if not qss:
            super().paint(qp, opt, index)
            return
        self._fakeView.setStyleSheet('#_fakeCopy::item {{\n\t{}\n}}'.format(
            '\n\t'.join(qss)))
        vopt = QStyleOptionViewItem(opt)
        self.initStyleOption(vopt, index)
        style = vopt.widget.style()
        style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, vopt, qp, self._fakeView)
```

Note that you *must* create the delegate with the view as its parent (which is what should be always be done, anyway).

In reality, if you want custom painting for each item, QSS is probably not the right choice: it may be easy, but such advanced painting customization isn't compatible with QSS in general. Just use custom delegates, ensure that you properly use the QStyle functions of the option's `widget` to get proper geometries and request drawings, and possibly consider to do the whole painting on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work: I am not sure this is the best way to do it or if it has any drawbacks, but it is fine for what I wanted.

I implemented a `QStyledItemDelegate` with a custom `paint()` method which draws the widget underneath according to the stylesheet and then draws text onto it according to the `ForegroundRole` data provided by the model.

```
class Alarm_Viewer_Style_Item_Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QObject] = None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

    def paint(self, painter: QPainter, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QModelIndex):
        self.initStyleOption(option, index)

        # Draw the widget, but exclude the text.
        option.text = ""
        style = option.widget.style() if option.widget else QApplication.style()
        style.drawControl(QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter, option.widget)

        # Get text color from model.
        if not option.state & QStyle.State_Enabled:
            cg = QPalette.Disabled
        elif option.state & QStyle.State_Active:
            cg = QPalette.Normal
        else:
            cg = QPalette.Inactive
        if option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            color = option.palette.color(cg, QPalette.HighlightedText)
        else:
            color = option.palette.color(cg, QPalette.Text)
        painter.setPen(color)

        # Display text over the empty item.
        text = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        painter.drawText(option.rect, option.displayAlignment, text)
```

The only downside is that I cannot fully control the styling from the stylesheet, but have to provide a `Alarm.level` -> `QColor` map to the model programmatically.

I tried to circumvent the inability to set properties on the list items by doing `option.widget.setProperty("alarm-level", alarm.level)` in  the paint method, but it did not work, unfortunately.

If anyone has any comment on this solution or ideas on how to control the styling from the stylesheet I'll gladly hear it.